# Hunt for rogue government agent who's using surgical brain alteration

Tags: story-identification, horror

I'm trying to find a book I've read.

In the story the protagonist is hunting down a rogue government agent (rogue spook) who's particularly good at a surgical brain modification technique developed in his agency. This agent has been going around making modifications for certain extreme mind states.

At the end of the book (pretty sure it was the last page),

> a child the protagonist knows says something like, "I love you *so* much!" in a way that implies the child has been modified for extreme parental love.

English, possibly published between 2000 and 2010. The book mainly follows the protagonist's hunt for the rogue and the covers some of the victims that are found.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! When was this written, approximately? What language was it in? Can you describe any additional plot points? Please try to provide some more detail, otherwise I'm afraid this question is likely to be put on hold.

Comment: Yeah. Some of this is pretty helpful (particularly the last part), but it might take more details.

Comment: Updated. Unfortunately that's about all I can recall currently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neuropath by R. Scott Bakker

From [goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3170310-neuropath):

> Tom's life is not what it once was. His marriage to the beautiful Nora is on the rocks and he now sees his two young children only on her say-so. His best friend Neil has moved to California to teach neurology. He has one success - a book on human psychology. Tom wiles away the time trying to teach bored grad students. But that all changes when Neil comes back into his life. For it seems that Tom's best friend was working for the National Security Agency, cracking the minds of suspected terrorists. Now it is Neil himself who has cracked and gone AWOL - what's more, he has left behind evidence that he has been employing his unique skills on civilians - obsessed with the idea that he can control the human brain.
>
> Thus begins a terrifying sequence of events as Neil starts to kidnap and mutilate people with a connection to Tom. He damages their brains and then releases them - often leaving them mad. But only when he gets near his ultimate target does he reveal the full horror of his plan . . .

The last page of the book has the scene with the child:

> 'Mommy?' a little girl's voice whispered.
>   Thomas heard the sharp intake of Nora's breath.
>   'I love you, Mommy.''I love you too,' she rasped.
>   'Yesss,' Ripley said. 
>   'I really, really, love you…'
>   The words were right, but the world that gave them meaning was so very wrong. Soon, Thomas realized, his son would awake also.Then the screaming would begin.
>   'I luvvvvvv…' his daughter cooed in a smiling, teary-eyed voice.
>   'Shhhh,' Thomas croaked. 'Time to sleep, honey.'

Comment: I have the book and I've extended your answer with the scene involving the child.

Comment: You know, the rest of the book didn't bother me but the ending bit really kicked me in the throat.